# How to refactor localizable.strings?

Tags: xcode, refactoring

I'm rather new to Objective C (I'm using Xcode, if it's relevant). I tried to find an answer to this, but couldn't find anywhere...
My question is: Is there a possible way to change a variable name in the Localizable.strings file, so that it would change in the entire app?
I do not want to use the "search and replace" option, since if there are more instances of that string which are not this variable's name, they would change too (which is something I'm interested to avoid).
Basically I'm interested in finding the parallel function to java's "refactor", while using eclipse. Thanks to all helpers!

Answer (score 1):

No, not possible to do it automatically. At least not in XCode - maybe AppCode can offer something, but I doubt it. Localizable.strings is not code - it's a text file which contains key-value pairs. Thus there are no real references to keys in your code, just same string values in your code and in the file.

Comment: I see. This info will come in handy. Thanks!!